# Python: Variables aren't re-assigned

Tags: python, function, variables

Why aren't the variables below (A,B,C,D) changed when *tst* is called.

```
A,B,C = 0,0,0
D = 0

def tst():
    A,B,C = 1,2,3
    D = 4
    print(A,B,C,D)

tst() # tst is called
print(A,B,C,D)

Output:

(1, 2, 3, 4)
(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

because of Python scoping rules.

in def tst(), you're creating local variables A, B, and C, and assigning them new values.

if you wish to assign to the global A,B, and C values, use the global keyword.

Answer (score 1):

The variables within the `tst` method are *local*, that is, they refer to different values that only exist inside scope of that method. Use the keyword `global` (as in `global A,B,C,D`) inside `tst` to fix the behavior. See an example [here](http://www.wellho.net/resources/ex.php4?item=y105/locvar.py) and the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them).